# Principle of Stationary Action and Euler-Lagrange Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, functional-derivatives

> **Principle of Stationary Action:**
>
> Given a mechanical system, there exists an action $S$ such that it is extremitized, or $\delta S=0$, for the actual motion of the system.
>
> $$S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(q, \dot{q}, t)dt$$
>
> where $L$ is the Lagrangian of the system.
>
> **Euler-Lagrangian Equation:**
> $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\bigg) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$$

My understanding that the extremum of S implies that the E-L Equation is satisfied.

My question is: Does it work the other way? i.e. Given a mechanical system, is demanding $\delta S = 0$ for its action equivalent to demanding $\frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\big) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$ for its Lagrangian?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/907/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69077/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122486/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209344/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The  Euler- lagranges equations are only a necessary condition for action to be extremum  -not sufficient condition -   For other sufficient conditions, see Gelfand & Fomin 2000. Chapter 5:        see Gelfand and Fomin (2000)Silverman, Richard A., ed. Calculus of variations (Unabridged repr. ed.). Mineola, New York: Dover Publications. p. 3. ISBN 978-0486414485."The Second Variation.Chapter 6: "Fields. Sufficient Conditions for a Strong Extremum". Sufficient conditions for a strong minimum are given by the theorem on p. 148.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative) of a functional $S[q]$ with respect to the function $q(t)$ is *defined* as
$$
\frac{\delta S[q]}{\delta q(t)}\equiv \lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{S[q+\alpha\delta_t]-S[q]}{\alpha}
$$
where $\delta_t$ is the Dirac delta function centered at $t$.

Your professor/book probably proved that the functional derivative coincides with the Euler-Lagrange derivative,
$$
\frac{\delta S[q]}{\delta q(t)}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}
$$
which means $\delta S=0$ **iff** E-L is satisfied. This means: as the functional derivative equals the E-L derivative, both are zero or neither is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise and clear explanation!