Minimality of the action
How is it proved that the extremal of the action obtained with Hamilton's principle in classical mechanics or classical field theory is in fact a minimum of the action and not just a stationary point? Furthermore how does one show that this minimum is unique? Is it correct to state that the uniqueness of the minimal path follows from the ability to apply the Picard-Lindeloef theorem to the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/907/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69077/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122486/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144356/2451 and links therein.

In the case of Hamilton's stationary action: there are also classes of cases such that the true trajectory corresponds to a maximum of Hamilton's action. The true trajectory corresponds to a point in variation space such that the derivative of Hamilton's action is zero. That is: it is about stationary action. The thing is: for Hamilton's action the choice between ($E_k-E_p$) and ($E_p-E_k$) is a arbitrary choice. The question of minimum/maximum has no impact on the result. I submit this is a case where Occam's razor is applicable: the criterion derivative-is-zero is sufficient.
